# Хочу стать web-разработчиком . Прошу совета успешных .

Tags: веб-программирование

Добрый день . Хочу поменять профессию (сейчас никак не связанную с IT ) и стать web-разработчиком . Конкретную специализацию еще не выбрал , так как не знаю тонкостей технологий , поэтому собираюсь во-первых изучить основы , такие как : HTML , CSS , JS , PHP . Вопрос собственно состоит в том , какой способ наиболее эффективен : самообучение , on-line курсы ? Вроде и хочется , чтоб был учитель , наставник , но про какие онлайн курсы отзывы не читал , ничего хорошего . Вобщем прошу совета опытных и успешных Web разработчиков . Буду признателен .

Comment: Кажется, вопрос касается опыта самоорганизации.

Comment: Попробуйте разные методики обучения и тогда поймете, что именно ДЛЯ ВАС является лучше, потому что нет точного ответа, все очень индивидуально.

Comment: @andreyqin
Согласен, в таком вопросе нужно знать особенности своего мышления/памяти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой сфере постоянное самообразование это норма. Поэтому "самообучение **или** on-line курсы" -- неправильный подход. Правильный: "чем мне ускорить и улучшить моё самообучение?"
За курсы (для начинающих) не скажу -- не посещал, но мне кажется в инете полно статей и курсов для чайников. С помощью них можно за пару дней освоить (на базовом уровне) HTML и CSS, ещё пара статей -- и у вас общее представление о PHP (или Рубин, Питон...). А уж после -- берите и делайте какой-либо проект. Получится криво и ужасно, но сделав один маленький проект вы получите больше опыта, чем на всех курсах Мира и уже будете иметь представление что к чему и куда вам интересно.

http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=html%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&clid=1923020

http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=css%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&clid=1923020&lr=213

ну и т.д.

Comment: Опять же качество курса может повлиять на фундамент.

Comment: Может. Но пока человек не в теме он не отличит хорошие курсы от плохих. Потому, думаю, лучше быстрее начать, а уж потом -- совершенствоваться, читая авторитетные книги и морща мозг : ) Может он вообще бросит эту тему и уйдет, например, в продвигальщики : )

Comment: Интересно знать, это сколько ему времени по 4м пунктам придется копаться, чтобы накопить опыт ошибок использования некачественных источников)))))

Comment: @mayar, Вы обратили внимание, человек хочет поменять **профессию, никак не связанную с IT?**

Сомневаюсь, что вообще возможно, прочитав несколько статей научиться программировать (что бы кто ни говорил, а сайтостроительство это самое настоящее программирование).

Для успеха в этой области надо набраться опыта (набить шишки) на сотнях маленьких искусственных задачек (обычно это упражнения в конце главы в учебнике) и потратить на это кучу времени (годы).

Набивание же шишек на *проектах*, выглядит слишком болезненным и честно говоря, сомнительным, в смысле достижения результата.

Comment: Есть предположение, что слово проект означает для вас "работа выполняемая на заказ за деньги". Я же под проектом понимаю придумывание и создание любого продукта. Например домашняя страничка на чистом ХТМЛ про своего любимого кота -- тоже проект.

Comment: Да, нет (в смысле "работа выполняемая на заказ за деньги"), конечно. Домашняя страничка для себя это тоже проект. 

Программирование же появится как только он захочет какой-то динамики (поиск по времени, месту и т.п.).

Comment: Тема "Хочу стать web-разработчиком", а не программистом. В этой сфере есть и верстальщики, и проектировщики, и дизайнеры и ещё много разных специализаций напрямую с написанием кода не связанных.

Comment: Ребята , огромное спс за ответы . Примерно так я и думал , что нужно просто читать и практиковать днями ночами . Главное выработать правильный и последовательный план обучения азов , а далее по мере необходимости приобретать новые знания и технологии . Сейчас занимаюсь c помощью "codecademy" , заодно английский вспомню ))

Answer (score 2):

Онлайн-курсы очень часто имеют отвратное качество.

Хорошие курсы у pluralsight'а, но они на английском и платные (по идее).

http://learn.javascript.ru/ - очень хороший сайт, сделанный в форме учебника - советую начать с него.

И лазить по всяким форумам и смотреть, что люди спрашивают и что отвечают. Пытаться сделать такое самому.